# What language do I need to learn to make make a script for my Epson receipt printer? (Manual link included)

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

**The printer:** TM-T88V
**The Manual:** https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/pos/bulk/tmt88v_swum_reve.pdf
**A receipt-marker Web template for the printer:** http://www.i-pos.nl/epson/
(Provided by Epson)

I'm a noob that doesn't know any computer languages. I've dug all I can but I still can't make sense of it all. I still don't know what I need to learn to print the receipts I want to print. 
There's mention of XML, HTML, CSS, and Javascript. But I don't know which one I need to learn. And I don't want to waste time learning one I don't need for this specific purpose.

What I want is to make a receipt that looks very similar to that of another business who makes wonderful receipts, and who uses this printer.

Ideally this is just a txt document or something very simple that I can manually change the lines of and click print. I do not need any sort of POS program with text boxes, buttons, or anything on a website for now. I just need a simple, off-line, on-my-desktop type solution. I want to plug the printer into my computer, change a few lines of text or code, and print it and have it look like their receipt, except with my logo and address.

Even if I can figure out how to print a receipt I manually made in Illustrator. I'm content doing that as well.

Please help me figure this out.

**Edit:** Would it at all be possible to pay someone to make some sort of noob-friendly setup where I just change lines of text and click print and get the result I want? 
Would this be costly?
Would I be better off learning how to do this myself?

Comment: Apparently, you can use something called [ESC/POS](https://mike42.me/blog/what-is-escpos-and-how-do-i-use-it). But I presume you need to write code in some other language so you're able to send such commands to printer port; such language can possibly be any that's able to open network sockets.

Comment: Javascript is the only programming language of the ones you listed. XML and HTML are [markup languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language). CSS is a styling language which adds style (shocker) to the generic markup that was given by XML or HTML. (Don't take this comment on what's useful and what isn't, I'm just providing context on what each are)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this manual, page 64](https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/pos/bulk/tm-t88v-i_fw3_trg_en_reve.pdf), it'll be Javascript. But this document talks about the TMT88V-i, and you have a TMT88V. I'd suggest you to try this out in order to be fixed.

Comment: Did use the same link as me? 
The manual is definitely for the TM-T88V. 
 https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/pos/bulk/tmt88v_swum_reve.pdf

Comment: As said in my answer : `this document talks about the TMT88V-i, and you have a TMT88V`